# Eclipse: Missing "Run Configurations" button? (Command Groups Availability not helpful)

Tags: eclipse, button, run-configuration

I have a weird problem.  I'm using Eclipse to make something in Python with PyDev.  Fine.  But one day, the Run Configurations button decides to vanish; now I can't run my program from within Eclipse!  Going to Window -> Customize Perspective -> Command Groups Availability doesn't help, because the Launch Command Group is missing for some reason!  I have no idea what could have caused this.  I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being the genius I am, I never thought to simply delete my Eclipse configurations.  For Linux users, that's in `/<your workspace>/.metadata`.

Comment: Sometimes, restarting eclipse will fix this problem.